# Accessing an object over class

Tags: vb.net

When reading an old project of mine I found something suspicious where I don't really understand why this part is working:

```
Public Shared Sub getXMLforProject(QueryString As String)
    Dim linkStart As String = "http://example.org"
    Dim linkEnd As String = "&tempMax=2000"
    Dim target As String = linkStart & QueryString & linkEnd

    'replaces parts that need encoding,
    'groups(1) is the sign e.g. <= and groups(2) is the text that needs encoding
    'groups(0) is the text of the full match (sign and encoding text)
    target = rx.Replace(target, Function(m As Match) encodeURLString(m.Groups(1).Value) + encodeURLString(m.Groups(2).Value))

    GUI.WebBrowser.Navigate(target)
    Return True
End Sub
```

the respective path that seams suspicious to me is the line

```
GUI.WebBrowser.Navigate(target)
```

There is a class called GUI that realises the user interface, but in the file context there is no objects named "GUI" available, so the access must be done by using the class. How is it possible for this to work? Is there an implicit mechanism that redirects the call from the GUI-class to the GUI-object?

Comment: `GUI` _must_ exist somewhere.  What happens if you select it and press F12 - usually in visual studio it will take you to where it is declared.  Also FYI - if you want to replace web addresses in things like this, try using http://example.com or http://example.org - they exist for just this reason

Comment: thanks for the hint, replaced it.
Visual Studio actually leads me to the class definition it self, not an object of the class

Comment: Is it some sort of static/shared class, that has a static/shared `WebBrowser` property?

Comment: no, the bowser is declared as: `Public WithEvents WebBrowser As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` while the class as `Public Class GUI`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using VB.NET, it emulates the behavior of the Form class from earlier Visual Basic editions where using the *type name* was a legal way to refer to an *instance* of the class.  Kinda necessary to give programmers a fighting chance to convert their VB6 projects.  Underlying plumbing is the [My.Forms object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87y2hdsf.aspx).

So, 99.9% odds are that the GUI class derives from System.Windows.Forms.Form.  Especially given that it has a WebBrowser member.  The Form is the host window for the browser.